# ncurses: how to refresh a single panel

Tags: ncurses

when using ncurses without panels, one can use `wrefresh` and `wnoutrefresh` to refresh a single window; but come with panels is another function `update_panels`, which seems to do the same thing as `wnoutrefresh`, but for all panels, and taking the stack order into account;

its [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/update_panels) page says:

> Use this function and not wrefresh or wnoutrefresh.

my question is: is it possible to refresh a single panel, like a single window, without calling `update_panels`? i tried both `wrefresh` and `wnoutrefresh` on a single panel but the result looks weird with both functions;

fyi: i would like to refresh a single panel instead of all panels because i think this may incur less overhead, but i am not sure if this is true or important; if performance is not an issue i think i am ok with refreshing all panels using `update_panels`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you cannot do that (ncurses will only repaint things that have changed, and unlike the window-oriented calls, [update_panels](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) takes into account overlapping panels)